# Using single ngOnDestroy in parent component

Tags: angular, inheritance, rxjs6

In our application we have some components that inherit from a `BaseComponent`.

The base component implements `OnDestroy` interface and emits with a Subject to notify the children to unsubscribe from eventual open streams.

Is this an acceptable approach or rather every single component should have its own `ngOnDestroy` implementation? From this [article](https://medium.com/@saniyusuf/part-1-the-case-for-component-inheritance-in-angular-a34fe2a0f7ac) I read that Lifecycle hooks are **not** inherited.

**BaseComponent**

```
export abstract class ComponentBase implements OnDestroy {
  protected destroy$ = new Subject<boolean>();

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next(true);
  }
}
```

**ChildComponent**

```
export class ChildComponent extends ComponentBase implements OnInit {

 ngOnInit() {
    this.service
      .getById(userId)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)) // this is emitted by the parent
      .subscribe(user => { ...}
 }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `ComponentBase` class? Only giving access to `destroy$`?

Comment: At the moment yes.

Comment: I think "at the moment" is a problem for me. I've never had much luck with base component classes. They grow quickly, become coupled to tons of components and then you want to rip them out and wish you never did that.

Comment: We have a first release in one month. After that moment a new release is planned for Autumn, therefore I can keep an eye whether this base class would grow too much or not. My concerns were though more on the relationship child/base class and using only one ngOnDestroy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this an acceptable approach or rather every single component should have its own ngOnDestroy implementation?

Acceptable is just a matter of opinion, but I would *strongly* discourage this approach for the following reason.

```
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnDestroy {
      public ngOnDestroy() {
         // do work
      }
}

export class BaseComponent implements OnDestroy {
      public ngOnDestroy() {
         // never executed
      }
}
```

There is no TypeScript warning issued for the above example that the *super* method is never executed, and so I would be tempted to call this an *anti-pattern*.

Furthermore, in the future you will be *tempted* to add additional lifecycle hooks like `OnInit` to the base class. To which, you'll have to search all of the *descendants* to ensure they call `super.ngOnInit()`.

While it might seem like more work but it is *safer* to use encapsulation.

```
export class BaseComponent implements OnDestroy {
     public ngOnDestroy() {
        // do work
     }
}

@Component({...})
export class MyComponent implements OnDestroy {
  private readonly _base: BaseComponent = new BaseComponent();
  public ngOnDestroy() {
     this._base.ngOnDestroy();
  }
}
```

There are a lot of articles on the net about the pros/cons between encapsulation vs. inheritance. It's actually a lengthy discussion in computer science, and some programming languages don't support inheritance specifically because of the problems. I guess I'm trying to say that this is a broad topic and a matter of personal choice for you, but it's partly why you asked the question.

https://www.developer.com/design/article.php/3525076/Encapsulation-vs-Inheritance.htm

Comment: We had similar views. The approach I explained in my question was not my idea, but it came from another member of my team. I will discuss it further in the next days.

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE 9th of Sept 2020:**
We've released a library at work that is safe to use with Ivy and that gives you access to all the component lifecycles as observables: https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-observable-lifecycle

That said, the PR which was supposed to fix this upstream in Angular itself has been merged and released recently (can't remember the release but have a look!)

**UPDATE 18th of May 2020:**
The following doesn't work anymore with Ivy as explained here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/36776

There's a PR to restore that behavior here: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/35464

Even though it's not as flexible, in the meantime you can use this: https://github.com/ngneat/until-destroy

---

If you're using the `ComponentBase` to only give you access to `destroy$` I'd say it's a bit overkill. You might need extending another class and Typescript doesn't support multiple inheritance so try to avoid that unless it's really necessary.

That said, if you're simply looking for a method to easily unsubscribe in a reactive way, please look at the following:

```
/**
 * Easily unsubscribe from an observable stream by appending `takeUntilDestroyed(this)` to the observable pipe.
 * If the component already has a `ngOnDestroy` method defined, it will call this first.
 * Note that the component *must* implement OnDestroy for this to work (the typings will enforce this anyway)
 */
export function takeUntilDestroyed<T>(component: OnDestroy): (source: Observable<T>) => Observable<T> {
  return (source: Observable<T>): Observable<T> => {
    const onDestroy = new Subject();
    const previousOnDestroy = component.ngOnDestroy;

     component.ngOnDestroy = () => {
      if (previousOnDestroy) {
        previousOnDestroy.apply(component);
      }

       onDestroy.next();
      onDestroy.complete();
    };

     return source.pipe(takeUntil(onDestroy));
  };
}
```

And then from your component just do `this.myObs$.pipe(takeUntilDestroyed(this))`

You can find that function and a demo usage in this PR too:
https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-sub-form/pull/41/files#diff-5796510f30fdd5bede9d709ce53ef225R45

Comment: The main idea so far was to avoid having to implement ngOnDestroy for each child component, but make it only once for the parent one.

Comment: Just like in your demo, you'll need to implements `OnDestroy` and declare an empty `ngOnDestroy` method. That's it, nothing more. If you don't, I think it'll work without AOT (?) not sure try it :)

Comment: Nice operator. Feels hacky to me, but I guess someone got tired of the boilerplate code for emitting destroy events. I know I get tired of it. I wish Angular made this a standard feature for all components to emit a destroy observable.

Comment: What happens if `previousOnDestroy` is *undefined*? When does Angular check that a component has the method `ngOnDestroy`? Is this checked at the destruction time?

Comment: Well nothing would error because of `if (previousOnDestroy)` but it'll still emit with next and complete so you'll correctly unsubscribe from your streams into your original component

Answer (score 0):

Its a valid approach but its better to use async pipe instead of subscribe and add onPushStrategy for better performance if that is you want to achieve https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/.

Comment: In our case we need to work further with the received data, therefore we cannot use async pipe. We use already OnPush change detection though.